# Can't get the value of an attribute with Selenium RC using xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm trying to get the first href attribute in a page using Selenium RC (in Python):

```
sel.get_text("xpath=//@href")
```

this returns an empty string.

However, an identical xpath on the same page inside Firefox (using the "View XPath" extension) yields the correct value.

I've tried fiddling with it, but the same happens for other attributes (eg @class) -- is there something awfully wrong with selenium or am I overlooking something trivial here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved by using selenium's get_attribute e.g. `sel.get_attribute("xpath=//a@href")` for a nodes.

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium RC, you can use the get_attribute function as below.

```
AttrValue = sel.get_attribute("//li[@id='result_0']/div/div[3]/div/a@href")
```

where `//li[@id='result_0']/div/div[3]/div/a` is the xpath.

`xpath=` is not required inside the function.

Answer (score -1):

I think this applies to all types of elements:

For example: for an input type of element

```
selenium.getAttribute("//input@value");
```